# Checking for auth cookie not working

Tags: php, ajax, cookies

I am setting up my first authentication system.The program saves the authentication data in a cookie after registration/login. It's works fine,and can recognize, whether user is logged in or not when trying to signup/login (via cookie check).
Now I want to check for the existence of the cookie condition on page load. I'm trying with an ajax call for a php script:

**JS**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post("check_user.php", function(data){
       alert(data);
    });
});
```

**php**:

```
<?php

    include("connection.php");

    if(isset($_COOKIE["auth_k"]))
        echo "cookies!!!!"; 

?>
```

But this does alert blank. While if I remove the isset condition in the php script the string gets returned to the js script normally.
It looks like the system doesn't find the cookie to be there on page load.

What am i doing wrong here? or am i missing something?

Comment: What does `var_dump($_COOKIE);` output?

Comment: It returns just the right value. Anyway now it's working, I don't understand what actually caused the problem. I am working with mamp so possibly it has to do with that. Wrong settings or something... Anyway thanks for the help!